# Color palettes generator for Office UI Fabric

Tags: office365

By default color palettes has been provided for Accent color: #0078d7. In same way how to generate the color palettes for different accent colors that are available in https://dev.office.com/fabric#palettes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Office UI Fabric team member here. Sorry for the delay. We don't currently have a tool to generate this palette, but it's something we're actively looking into since we need something like for some of our own product scenarios. I'll keep this space posted as we work on this.